# Why is integration of Taylor series allowed?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

We can find the integrals of various functions by instead integrating their Taylor series form term by term.

Of course such a claim cannot simply be made lightly. What I was wondering was, for what reason are we allowed to do this?

Comment: If the series uniformly converges on some interval [(in particular, if the power series has a non-zero radius of convergence)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Differentiation_and_integration), then this is legit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Clement C. gave the answer, but let me shine some light as to why. Basically this is due to the [Fubini-Tonelli Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) (i.e. changing the order of integration). You may write the sum as an integral over the counting measure (I'm assuming you've seen basic 2d integral calculus)
$$ \int_{x_0}^x \left (\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n(s) \right) ds = \int_{x_0}^x \left(\int_{\mathbb{N}} a_n(s) dn\right) ds $$
we may change the order of integration if
$$ \int_{x_0}^x \int_{\mathbb{N}} | a_n(s)| dn ds < \infty$$
by Fubini's Theorem. If the series is absolutely convergent for $s\in (a,b)$, we know that
$$ \int_{\mathbb{N}} |a_n(s) | dn = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n(s)| < \infty $$
Thus the theorem condition is satisfied, so
$$  \int_{x_0}^x \left (\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n(s) \right) ds=\int_{x_0}^x \left(\int_{\mathbb{N}} a_n(s) dn\right) ds =  \int_{\mathbb{N}}\left(\int_{x_0}^x a_n(s) ds\right) dn  = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N} } \int_{x_0}^x a_n(s) ds$$